# docker containers unable to communicate to each other due to https certificate "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, identityserver4

i have a solution with multiple projects in vs2019 and they are run using docker-compose in vstudio 2019.

- asp.net core api (api1)
- asp.net core api (api2)

**What i need to do**

- i need to have these two containers in docker be able to communicate to each other over https in my local.

**here's what i've done so far.**

- generate certificate using "dotnet dev-certs https -ep {location of cert} -p {password}"
- execute command "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" in my windows machine.
- connect to api1 & api2 container and converted the "pfx" files to "crt" using openssl and then running "update-ca-certificates"
- i even added for both of the api's "docker-compose.override.yml" values for "ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password" and "ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path" and "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT"
- Testing communication between them by using curl on api1 container to query to api2 thru https. no luck, unless i put --k flag on curl calls but that is not the purpose here.

is there anyway i can make this work using a self-signed certificate? since this is just for dev purpose.